# Wrong mysql query syntax?

Tags: mysql, syntax

I have a question about my mysql query syntax

When i use this

```
$result = $db->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM `person`  WHERE '.$searchOn.' LIKE "%'.$critera.'%"  ');
```

The query returns a result.

But when using this query

```
$result = $db->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM `person`  WHERE "'.$searchOn.'" LIKE "%'.$critera.'%"  ');
```

The query returns nothing...

What is the difference between '.$searchOn.' and "'.$searchOn.'"?

Comment: SQL String literals are enclosed with `'` not `"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column name should not be quoted with single or double quote.

You have double quote arround the column name in where clause.

```
    $result = $db->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM `person`  
     WHERE "'.$searchOn.'" LIKE "%'.$critera.'%"  ');
```

Final Query:-

```
SELECT * FROM `person`  WHERE "field_name" LIKE ...
```

That is causing the mysql error.

You can enclose the column name in `` backticks to avoid any strange error again cause of mysql reserved words.

**EDIT**

Your query should be like this.

```
    $result = $db->executeQuery('SELECT * FROM `person`  
    WHERE `'.$searchOn.'` LIKE "%'.$critera.'%"  ');
```

Comment: Tnx for answer, but my php var is the column name so how do i set this syntax right in the query?

Comment: really tnx for you answer its working.

But when i extend my query like this

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `person` WHERE `'.$searchOn.'` LIKE %'.$critera.'% ORDER BY `'.$searchOn.'` ASC  LIMIT '.$start.', '.$per_page' ";

Its not working anymore.

I am sure that $start and $per_page contains values.
You got any suggestion?

Comment: @Down: Values should be in quotes why you removed double quotes from LIKE clause. I said column name should not enclosed with single or double quote

Comment: @Down: If this answer helped you to solve your problem, Consider to accept this answer you can accept by clinking the right arrow at the left of this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The columnname can't be in double quotes. If you want to use quotes use the ones you used for the table name.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is caused by wrong use of single- and double-quotations.

Try :

```
$result = $db->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person  WHERE ".$searchOn." LIKE %".$critera."%");
```

Or :

```
$result = $db->executeQuery("SELECT * FROM person  WHERE $searchOn LIKE %$critera%");
```

Both should work...

Basically like when you're concatenating a string and a variable in PHP...